# Is context:annotation-config an alternative to @AutoWired?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

Is it correct that I can put `context:annotation-config` in my XML config and it will automatically inject the bean class without needing any annotations?

So instead of using these annotation types:

```
public class Mailman
{
    private String name;

    @Autowired
    private Parcel Parcel;

    public Mailman(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setParcel(Parcel Parcel)
    {
        this.Parcel = Parcel;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void directionsToParcel(Parcel Parcel)
    {
        this.Parcel = Parcel;
    }

}
```

I would just need to write this:

```
<beans ... >
<bean id="mailMan" class="MailMan">
 <constructor-arg value="John Doe"/>
</bean>
<bean id="parcel" class="Parcel" />
<context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

and then my MailMan class would look a lot simpler without the need for annotations:

```
public class Mailman
{
    private String name;

    private Parcel Parcel;

    public Mailman(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, a Spring context will pay no attention to `@Autowired` annotations. In order to process them, the context needs to have a `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean registered in the context.

`<context:annotation-config/>` registers one of these for you (along with a few others), so you do need it (unless you register `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` yourself, which is perfectly valid).

If you don't like having `@Autowired` in your code, then you can explicitly inject properties in the XML using `<property>`, which just moves the clutter from one place to another.

If your context is *extremely* simple, then you can use implicit autowiring, as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire). Essentially, this tells Spring to autowire automatically by property name or type. This required very little configuration, but it very quickly gets out of control - it's automatic nature means it's hard to control, and gives you very little flexibility.

`@Autowired` really is the best option, in general.

Answer (score 1):

`<context:annotation-config />` just auto-registers all the standard bean post processors provided by Spring like `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, so that you don't have to register them individually in your spring context file. You still have to provide the `@Autowired` annotations on the attributes/setter as earlier.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`@Autowired` Annotations are needed on the class along with  `<context:annotation-config/>`

The xml config part is not needed when using the annotations.

Also from the doc Note that `<context:annotation-config/>` only looks for annotations on beans in the same application context it is defined in. This means that, if you put   in a WebApplicationContext for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for @Autowired beans in your controllers, and not your services.

If you dont need to use annotations then you need to specify the xml configuration.