# Why this bean isn't injected?

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-security, autowired

I'm quite used to use Spring and Spring Security, but i can't figure out why here dependency injection isn't working.
I have an application with two basic authentication system, one for the users and one for the two administrators. This is the security-context.xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
    class="com.foo.bar.service.LoginServiceImpl" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl" />
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <user-service>
            <user name="AdminOne" password="eh223rh2efi9hfuwefugwg"
                authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="AdminTwo" password="wdkjbcfwerjkbiwfviwefi"
                authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

The user authentication rely on this implementetaion of UserDetailsService:

```
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserDetailsDAO dao;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    try {
        // Get the credentials
        return credentials;
    } catch (NoResultException exc) {

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username not found");
    } catch (JDBCException jdbce) {
        throw new DataAccessException("Cannot acess db", jdbce) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is that the field `UserDetailsDAO` is null. So is not injected. The strange thing is that in testing enviroment everything works fine. And no exceptions are thrown during server startup, that is also strange since usually errors in autowiring are reported. 
By the way, the authentication of administrators works like a charm.

If can be useful, this is the web.xml:
foo

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Foo Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        <!-- Here the context specific for a single project -->
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/datasource-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StreamViewer Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    <!-- Here the context for all the projects -->
        /WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have `<context:annotation-config />` in your `security-context.xml` to enable [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) which sets the values of `@Autowired` annotated fields.

From documentation:

> A default
>   AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered by the
>   "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags.
>   Remove or turn off the default annotation configuration there if you
>   intend to specify a custom AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean
>   definition.

See [Is context:annotation-config an alternative to @AutoWired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985030/is-contextannotation-config-an-alternative-to-autowired)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use autowiring you will need to scan for beans rather than declaring them explicitly in your xml file.

You should replace

```
<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
    class="com.foo.bar.service.LoginServiceImpl" />
```

with:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />
```

and annotate your LoginServiceImpl class with:

```
@Service(name="userDetailsServiceImpl")
```